# Stable Marriage / Stable Matching / Gale-Shapley where men rank a subset of women

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, algorithms, matching-theory

> Given n men and n women, preference rankings for the women, does Gale-Shapley still find a stable matching if the **men only rank a subset of women**.

From this variation, it's possible that we end up with single people, but that's ok as this situation is still stable.

- In this variation, some men may not be matched to a woman
- But in that case, the man is content being single
- Since women rank all men, some woman preferred that man, but that man didn't prefer that woman
- Therefore having unmatched men and women is stable since

My problem is justifying the rest of the matching is also stable
Do I prove it by contradiction?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Gayle-Shapely fails to find the matching somteimes

Suppose that we have 2 men and 2 women. Suppose that $m_1$ has preference
ranking $w_1$, $w_2$, and $m_2$ has preference ranking $w_1$ (and vetoes $w_2$).
Also suppose that $w_1$ has ranking $m_1$, $m_2$. The ranking for $w_2$ is unknown but doesn't matter. Now, there is 1 perfect matching of men to women they have not vetoed.
**Namely, match $m_2$ to $w_1$ and $m_1$ to $w_2$**. However, this is not stable, since $m_1$ and $w_2$ prefer each other over such a matching.

(The matching in which $m_1$ is matched to $w_1$ and $m_2$, $w_2$ remain isolated is stable but Gayle-Shapely fails to find it.)

Comment: This is incorrect. Gale-Shapley *does* find the stable matching in which $m_1$ is matched to $w_1$, while $m_2$ and $w_2$ remains single.  According to the G-S algorithm, $m_1$ proposes to $w_1$ who accepts.  Then $m_2$ proposes to $w_1$ who rejects (because she prefers $m_1$).  Now $m_2$ has no more proposals to make (since he vetoed $w_2$) so he remains single.  The algorithm ends.  $m_1$ is paired to $w_1$ while $m_2$ and $w_2$ remain single.

Comment: Who is $h_2$ in this example?

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan Oops, I meant $w_2$, fixed

Comment: Ok but the error in the proof pointed out a year ago is still there now.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine you're the president-for-life and you've decided that your population is too small and needs to grow, so you've made it a crime to be single!

Whenever someone, man or woman, refuses to rank everyone of the opposite sex, you simply invent a ranking for him, putting those he doesn't like *below* those that he does. Go by alphabetical order or draw lots, that doesn't matter. Then run the algorithm and force-marry everybody to whom the algorithm decides they should marry. Some of the marriages will be unhappy. Tough luck -- what are they gonna do, *sue* the president-for-life?

Now *in reality* those that ended up in an unhappy marriage in the thought experiment will instead be single. But the partial matching you have after dissolving the unhappy marriages will still be stable.

Namely if there's any pair of people who would choose to elope *in reality*, those two people would *still* choose to elope in the imaginary world. (They must like each other, so even if one or both of them is single, they would just be unhappily married in the imaginary world and therefore willing to elope with anyone they do like).

But Gale and Shapley tell us that the matching in the imaginary world; therefore nobody will elope in reality either.

Comment: I understand the force-marrying off & then dissolving part, but I don't quite 
get the part about people still eloping in both worlds. Doesn't Gale-Shapely say that there are none of these unstable matchings so no one could elope? If we marry someone who prefers to be single, is that stable? Or does it depend of if someone else prefers them?

Comment: @SleekPanther: Marying the singles off is only a thought experiment. It's an indirect proof: _If_ there were any pair who would elope in the real world where there are singles, _then_ the same pair would elope in the world of forced marriages. But Gale-Shaply says that is not possible. Therefore there is no elopings in the real world either.

Answer (score 2):

A more conventional solution here is that the argument for stable matchings in ordinary Gale-Shapley still applies here with essentially no modification. We take a pair $(M_1,W_1)$, and prove that it is not unstable.

We assume that at the end of Gale-Shapley, $M_1$ is not married to $W_1$ (if they were married, they definitely wouldn't be an unstable pair). Also, we assume that $M_1$ prefers $W_1$ to $M_1$'s current arrangement (if not, then the pair is definitely not unstable, since $M_1$ is happier where he is). It's irrelevant here whether $M_1$'s current arrangement is "single" or "married to some other woman $W_2$". Since $M_1$ makes proposals in order from best to worst, $M_1$ must have proposed to $W_1$ at some point before making it this far down the list.

Since $M_1$ did not end up with $W_1$, at some point $W_1$ must have rejected him in favor of someone better, or in favor of staying single. In Gale-Shapley, women only trade up; once $W_1$ rejects $M_1$, she will only be in situations higher and higher on her preference list. So, at the end of the algorithm, either $W_1$ is single (because she preferred staying single to being engaged to $M_1$) or $W_1$ is married to a man $M_2$ she prefers to $M_1$. In either case, $(M_1,W_1)$ is not an unstable pair: $W_1$ is happier where she is.

---

In particular, let's look at the situation described in another answer, where the rankings were:

- $m_1$: $w_1 > w_2 > \text{single}$
- $m_2$: $w_1 > \text{single} > w_2$
- $w_1$: $m_1 > m_2 > \text{single}$
- $w_2$: irrelevant.

In the first round of Gale-Shapley, $m_1$ and $m_2$ both propose to $w_1$. She picks $m_1$, whom she likes better. In the second round, $m_2$ does not propose to anyone, since he prefers being single to his remaining option $w_2$. So the final matching found by Gale-Shapley is $(m_1,w_1)$ with $m_2$ and $w_2$ remaining single.

There are no unstable pairs here: $m_1$ and $w_1$ got their best options, so they won't be part of any unstable pair, and $(m_2, w_2)$ is not an unstable pair either, since $m_2$ prefers being single to being married to $w_2$.